# use gulp to build my project throw error, how to resolve it

Tags: gulp, html-framework-7

[image]

Never encountered this problem before
i Can't find what the problem is

Comment: try to Update you gulp global and local  version

Comment: Also, make sure you are using the right file Eg: CSS or .scss file

Comment: CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: Unknown